# I have 3 questions about current source. I'm confused if the current source gives the final current in a mesh or do I still need to add/subtract

Tags: basic

[image]

I made up this simple circuit to show my problem. The title says my problem and you can see the three questions in the picture. I need to resolve this doubt so that I can form equations correctly.

Comment: some of the people here cannot view images ... to them, you did not ask any questions ... please add the three questions to your post

Comment: @jsotola thank you for responding, sorry I have a circuit diagram and my equation written here. and also arrows pointing from question to the problematic part, so I think i cannot substitute for images. but i got one answer here so i guess its fine.

Comment: Use Ohm's law; then KCL to find how the 2 A divides.

Answer (score 0):

\$I_2\$ is 2 A, without needing to write any equation, because the 2 A current source is only part of mesh 2.

You can't write a (useful) KVL equation for mesh 2, because of the current source.

You can find the current through the resistor directly, because there is a voltage source across it, so you know the voltage across it is 12 V. And therefore the current through it is 1.5 A.

Comment: thank you...so i'll put -2A in place of I2. Aside from that, is my kvl equations correct?

Comment: @Rafsan, no it isn't. The KVL equation should be that some sum of voltage drops equals 0. The "-2" term in your equation is presumably the current source's current, not its voltage drop. You could substitute something like \$V(I_{src})\$ in your equation, but since there's no way to write \$V(I_{src})\$ as a function of the mesh currents, because a current source produces the same current regardless of what voltage is across it, you can't use this equation to solve the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same equation using KVL on mesh2 as you do using KVL on mesh1. This is because there is 12 V across the 2 A current source. So there is no point in deriving both mesh equations, one mesh will do. From one mesh (either mesh), you can determine I1 and, because you know I2, you can determine the current in the 8R resistor. You only have one unknown (I1) so you only need one equation to find it.

But, this is all really unnecessary because the current in the 8R resistor just equals 12/8 = 1.5 A.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems mostly about what the circuit elements do - whether they're influenced by other things in the circuit. They're not. The 2 amp current symbol means that 2 amps is going through that element no matter what's going on elsewhere. Similarly, the 12 V element has exactly 12 V across it, always. Knowing that your problem only needs Ohm's Law for its solution. 12 V across 8 ohms tells you that 1.5 amps is flowing down through it. That means that the current source's 2 amps gets split into 1.5 amps through the resistor and 0.5 amps down through the 12 V source.